# Unable to switch properly between webpages

Tags: html, css

While I'm trying to switch between different sections of my webpage I am getting the following page as shown in the image. How can I solve this?[image: As shown in the image I have to select the .html file in order to open other section]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to provide context for your question for people being able to help you. I imagine you are trying to navigate between different html files, by clicking into an anchor tag, is that correct?

```
<a href="./next.html">Go to next page</a>
```

So in that case, you might be adding a wrong relative route, otherwise I think you should add more context to your question.

Comment: Sorry for that. Yes, I am trying to navigate between different html files

Comment: Did you try the "./" part in href?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to switch between sections on your webpage. Try adding section and giving them id. Then from any anchor tag you can reach the section by adding the following code.

```
<a href="./index.html/#section1">Section 1</a>
```

Comment: This could be just <a href="#section1">Section 1</a>

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery

```
 $(".div").load("index.php .yoursection");
```

Answer (score 0):

To switch between sections on your webpage,Use the id selector ,

Example:

```
<p id="opening">Hyperlinks are utilized by a web browser to move from one page to another...</p>
```

Now add the anchor tag to link,

```
<a href="#opening">Opening</a>
```

"Opening" will be displayed as a link on the webpage. On clicking it, you will be switched on the same webpage where the id is "Opening".
In this example it is the paragraph tag.

If you trying to switch into another webpage,

```
<a href="../home.html">Go to home page</a>
```